# Loading from database - inside or outside class?

Tags: oop

I've seen different ways of loading an object to and fro a database, with two common ones as shown below. Which one is better, and why?

**Method 1:** This includes defining two member methods for a class, `load(id)` and `save()`. These methods are called on instances of the class. For example,

```cs
class Wheel{
    double diameter;
    string tag;

    public void Load(int id){
        var result = ... // database query
        this.diameter = result['diameter'];
        this.tag = result['tag'];
    }

    public void Save(){
        ... // database query to update row
    }
}

Wheel johnWheel = new Wheel();
johnWheel.Load(5); // In this case John's wheel has a row id of 5 in the database
```

**Method 2:** A utility method which loads/saves an object directly:

```cs
class DBUtils{
    public static Wheel LoadWheel(int id){
        var result = ... // database query

        Wheel w = new Wheel();
        w.setDiameter(result['diameter']);
        w.setTag(result['tag']);
    }

    public static void SaveWheel(Wheel wheel){
        ...// Update DB
    }
}
```

---

I ask because the notion of a 'wheel' itself does not include functions which loads and saves it from a database, so perhaps **method 1** would be considered bad OOP design.

Comment: field names and db names have apparently the same name. I would go with introspection and automatize the process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both seem a bit off...

**Method 1**

For one thing, `Load()` should be a static factory in this case.  This usage is a bit obtuse:

```
Wheel johnWheel = new Wheel();
johnWheel.Load(5);
```

Between those two lines of code, what is `johnWheel`?  Is it in anything approaching a valid state?  If not, then it seems like its construction is a little broken.  OO principles would suggest encapsulating that into a single operation rather than expecting consuming code to perform multiple sequential operations every time.  If it's a static factory, the usage is simpler:

```
Wheel johnWheel = Wheel.Load(5);
```

**Method 2**

This one is more of a naming concern than a structure concern.  `DBUtils`?  That's going to turn into a dumping ground for unrelated functionality *quickly*.  You want to avoid that.  How about something like this?:

```
class WheelRepository
{
    public static Wheel Get(int id)
    {
        // ...
    }

    public static void Save(Wheel wheel)
    {
        // ....
    }
}
```

As an *object* (this is still OOP after all), a `WheelRepository` represents (and therefore encapsulates) very specific functionality whereas a `DBUtils` doesn't.

**Conclusion**

I generally prefer method 2 in a structural sense, because the *business object* (`Wheel`) shouldn't know anything about the *database* (`WheelRepository`).  The former is a core portable business concern, the latter is a periphery infrastructure concern.  My only caveat is that I'd recommend standard patterns for improving method 2, such as a combination of the Repository Pattern and the Unit Of Work pattern, for example.

Answer (score 1):

You should create a separate class that handles database connections and the creation/destruction of these connections. That way, the `wheel` is a separate entity from the database it is using.

Go with method 2.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with Method 2 (like laiello proposed). I would however not name the class DbUtils but more something like WheelDao or WheelRepository (if for instance your Wheel class is an Root entity in your domain model). 
If however you go with Method 1 the load(id) method should be static. Since it is not called on a particular instance of an object but it rather produces a new instance of an object. This is unlike the save() method for which it is correct to be called on a specific instance of Wheel.